# Subparagraph between two pages is not aligned correctly

Tags: paragraphs, mactex, texshop

I have a tex book document, containing chapters, sections, paragraphs and subparagraphs. The subparagraph that you see in the code is inside a section.
The problem is that if the subparagraph is between two pages, the PDF file shows a horizontal gap in the contents of the second page:

[image]

That's a MWE with two files:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright] {book} 
% Recognize accented lecters
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
% Include figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
% Generate table of contents and other things in italian
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
% Include code snippets with colored keywords
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
% Write underscore with \_ or \textunderscore
\usepackage{underscore}


\begin{document}

    \input{chapter1}


\end{document}
```

That's the chatper1 file:

```
\chapter{Introduzione a WebGL e three.js}


    \section{WebGL: una libreria grafica per il web}
    %Come? nato, cos?è WebGL e come viene utilizzato

        \paragraph{}
        WebGL è una libreria grafica per il web multipiattaforma e royalty-free, recentemente sviluppata, che permette di disegnare scene 2D e 3D realistiche.
        Scritta in Javascript, si basa sulla tecnologia di HTML 5. È stata sviluppata dall' organizzazione non-profit Khronos Group, a partire dal 2009 con l' aiuto di 
        Google, Apple, Mozilla, Opera e altre organizzazioni. È compatibile con la maggior parte dei browser moderni per desktop e per cellulare:

            \subparagraph{Browser per desktop}

            \begin{itemize}
                \item Mozilla Firefox - a partire dalla versione 4.0;
                \item Google Chrome - a partire dalla versione 9;
                \item Safari - a partire dalla versione 6.0 su OS X Mountain Lion, OS X Lion e dalla versione 5.1 su OS X Snow Leopard;
                \item Opera - a partire dalla versione 11 anche se disabilitato di default;
                \item Internet Explorer - a partire dalla versione 11 anche se il supporto è parziale. Tuttora non soddisfa molti test di conformità di WebGL.
            \end{itemize}

            \subparagraph{Browser mobili}

            \begin{itemize}
                \item Android Browser , su alcuni dispositivi Sony Ericsson e Samsung;
                \item Internet Explorer - su Windows Phone 8.1;
                \item BlackBerry PlayBook;
                \item Firefox Mobile - a partire dalla versione 4;
                \item Firefox OS;
                \item Google Chrome - a partire dalla versione 25;
                \item   Maemo - sui Nokia N900;
                \item Opera Mobile - solo su Android;
                \item Tizen 1.0;
                \item Ubuntu Touch;
                \item WebOS;
                \item iOS - solo tramite iAd da iOS 4.2.
            \end{itemize}
```

Comment: We certainly need to see more of your code, please prepare a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/). My crystal ball tells me though that this might be due to a `documentclass` - or other page set-up - that uses a two page mode with [recto and verso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recto_and_verso) pages. LaTeX then does not have a notion of left and right margin, but rather of inner and outer margins (which can be either on the left or the right side, depending on whether they are on a recto or verso page).

Comment: not related to your problem but you have omitted one level of the sectioning hierarchy, \section, \subsection\ paragraph, \subparagraph, which may cause some odd effects in table of contents layout and numbering, especially if you were ever to increase `secnumdepth`

Comment: You might be looking for the `oneside` option, i.e. `\documentclass[...,oneside,...]{book}` to turn off the alternating margins.

Comment: @HenriMenke I use the twoside options because I'll need to print the PDF and I want it on both sides of the papers.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri If you want to print a PDF on both sides of the paper, you are referring to the duplex option of your printer, while the `twoside` option adjusts the print space to alternate the margins for recto and verso pages. Further reading: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Print_space#Page_spread)

Comment: Well that solved my problem.

Comment: @HenriMenke I think, that is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal gap you see is due to the `twoside` option you used for the documentclass: this option sets different side margins for the *recto* (front) and the *verso* (back) of the paper sheet.

The inner margin is usually different from the outer margin.
Just to make an example: the inner margin of your page 1 (the *recto*) is the left margin.
But since page 2 is supposed to stay on the *verso* of the same sheet, its left margin is now the outer, and will be equal to the right margin of page 1.
That's why you see the horizontal gap.

If you want to avoid this behavior just change the `twoside` option to `oneside`.